# How to only call jQuery's "complete" once "success" has completely finished (and maintain long-polling)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using jQuery's `.ajax` function to retrieve a very long stream of JSON that contains images.

I want to execute a callback only once the JSON data has been parsed and only once all the images have been loaded into an array.  I then want to "re-poll". So far in my code, the `success` and `complete` callbacks are called before the data is loaded (even when the success function is in a while loop).

Can anyone show me how to only call the complete function when the entire success function has finished? Can I do this with jQuery's deferred or promises object, how how to keep a long-polling system going?

Here is my code

```
url: 'example.com'
$(function(){
    (function poll(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: streamUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: successFn,
            complete: poll //only call this once JSON has been parsed/images loaded. Then recall poll
        });
    }, 1500);
  })();
})

function successFn(data){
    entries = data.entries;
    x = entries.length;
        while(x--){
           console.log(entries[x]);
    }
    addToArray();

}
function addToArray(){
    //Add image URLs to array
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery.Deferred.

```
var def = $.Deferred();
$(function(){
    (function poll(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: streamUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: successFn,
            complete: addToArray //only call this once JSON has been parsed/images loaded
        });
    }, 1500);
  })();
})

function successFn(data){
    entries = data.entries;
    x = entries.length;
        while(x--){
           console.log(entries[x]);
    }
    alert('done'); //This is executed way before all entries are logged
    def.resolve();
}
function addToArray(){
    $.when(def).done(function(){
        //Add image URLs to array
    });
}
```

Comment: Or even more simply just call the "addtoarray" function at the end of your success callback function.

Comment: While using this method the `addToArray` function is still called early (an alert appears) while info is being logged to the console.   Could this just be a delay with my console (i.e. it just takes some time to actually appear)?

Comment: Michael, your answer is perfect for how I phrased the question originally, however I forgot to say that I need this to be in a long-polling set up, the `poll` function being called when all other functions have been completed.  Because `poll` is an anonymous closure I do not see where I can call it on finish.  I sent `addToArray` and `poll` in an array to complete but it did not work (too many calls). Any idea how I can implement long-polling here?